# s,q-closeness of finite supersolvable $T_{nsp}$-groups.

Tags: group-theory

DEFINITION
Let $G$  be a finite group and let $H$  be a subgroup of $G$. Then $H$ is
called nearly S-permutable in $G$ if for every prime $p$ such that $
(p,|H|)=1$, and for every subgroup $K$ of $G$ containing $H$, the normalizer 
$N_{K}(H)$ contains some $p$-Sylow subgroup of $K$, we shall denote this by (
$H$ is $nsp$ in $G$).

DEFINITION 
A finite group $G$ is called $T_{nsp}$- group if nearly S-permutability is
transitive among subgroups of $G$. That is, if $A$ is $nsp$ in $B$, and $B$
is $nsp$ in $G$, then $A$ is $nsp$ in $G$.

PROBLEM(A)
Is it possible to construct a finite supersolvable group $G$, such that, $G$
is $T_{nsp}$- group and $G$ has at least one subgroup $H$ that is NOT $
T_{nsp}$- group.

PROBLEM(B)
Should homomorphic image of a finite supersolvable $T_{nsp}$- group be a $
T_{nsp}$- group?

As for problem (A) I think that it is impossible to construct such group. If we remove the supersolvable condition then $A_5$ is an example of such groups. 
As for problem (B) I also think it is true, the problem with nearly S-permutibility is that it is not preserved under homomorphic images which (in my opinion) exclude the induction in the proof. 
I would be grateful if some one could help or recommend some reference.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Generally speaking, just posting a wall of text with problems at the end and none of your own work, doesn't do too well around here.

Comment: If $G$ is either abelian or $p$-group, then it is clear that the class of $T_{nsp}$-groups is both subgroup and homomorphic image closed. .

Comment: Using GAP all groups up to order 96 have no counter example showing that the subgroup of a supersolvable (finite) $T_{nsp}$-group is not $T_{nsp}$-group.

Comment: Do you know any examples of finite supersolvable groups that are not $T_{\rm nsp}$?

Comment: Yes, the group of smallest order that is Supersolvable not $T_{nsp}$-group is $G=C_{3} \times S_{3}$. If we take $A=<(1,(1,2))>$ then $A$ is cyclic and has order 6. Hence, Its nearly S-Permutable in $G$. Now we take $B=<(0,(1,2))> $.  Then, $B$ is Nearly S-permutable in $A$ (since it is normal in $A$), and $A$ is nearly S-permutable in G, but $B$ is not nearly S-permutable in G. Hence, $G$ is not $T_{nsp}$-group.

Comment: note $|G|=18=2 .3^2$, and $|A|=6=2.3$ so if $p$ is prime with $(p,|A|)=1$ then $(p,|G|)=1$ this is why $A$ is nearly S-permutable in $G$.

Comment: for $B$ we have $|B|=2$ if we take $K=G$ and we let $p=3$ then $(p,|B|)=1$ and $N=N_{G}(B)=N_{K}(B)=A$ and the $3$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ is not in $N$ which implies that $B$ is not nearly S-permutable in $G$.